# How to Sort List Items from Low to High Without Built-In Tools

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to write this function `gensort(list)` that takes a list of numbers and returns a new list with the same numbers, but ordered from low to high. An example of the output would be something like

```
>>> gensort([111, 1, 3.14])
[1, 3.14, 111]
```

I wrote a function to take one element and return it to its place in ascending oder:

```
def insert_sorted(elem,list):
       if list == []:
           return [elem]
       elif elem < list[0]:
           return [elem] + list
       else:
           return [list[0]] + insert_sorted(elem, list[1:])
```

Now I'm trying to apply it to the rest of my list and I came up with this:

```
def gensort(list):
    insert = insert_sorted(list[min],list)
    return insert
```

However, this doesn't work in the least. I'm wondering how I can use insert_sorted recursively, or write a different list comprehension to get it to return the correct order for my whole list.

I know there are built in sorting tools but I'm trying to write this with what I've got currently.

Comment: fix your indentation please.

Comment: There are plenty of sort algorithms - you look like you are trying to write an insertion sort - which sorts from the front. You could also do a bubble sort - which effectively sorts from the back - or a quick sort. There is plenty of information on line about the algorithm for the different types of sort. Also I would experiment with recursion on a simpler functionality, before you do something like this - as you will probably find it very difficult to debug.

Comment: The recursion used in insert_sorted looks fine, and the desire to write a sort function from scratch is commendable. I don't understand why this effort is being criticized.

Comment: Here's a bunch of sorts in Python/Cython (m4 preprocessed for both): http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/sort-comparison/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't ask whether creating your own sort function was a good idea, so I'll answer the question you asked, with one way of using insert_sorted to create a full gensort function:

```
def gensort(list):
    sorted_list = []
    for item in list:
        sorted_list = insert_sorted(item, sorted_list)
    return sorted_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use sort?
If you are putting there numbers only, simple do something like this:

```
insert_sorted(elem,list):
  list.append(elem)
  list.sort() // will sort in asc order
```

This is not a tool, it's standard functionality in python. Your method has big disadvantage, it will be slow and memory requiring on long lists. Better would be add new element to list and run sort function on it.

With your function adding an element to n element array, you will have n+1 function calls, creating n+1 subarrays. thats way to slow, and not acceptable. Use one loop sort algoritm instead, if you don't want to use python sort.

Example of bubble sort in python:

```
def bubble_sort(list_):
    """Implement bubblesort algorithm: iterate L to R in list, switching values
    if Left > Right. Break when no alterations made to to list. """
    not_complete = True
    while not_complete:
        not_complete = False
        for val, item in enumerate(list_):
            if val == len(list_)-1: val = 0
            else:
                if list_[val] > list_[val+1]:
                    list_[val], list_[val+1] = list_[val+1], list_[val]
                    not_complete = True
    return list_
```

Comment: MY advise -don;t reinvent the wheel:) Unless that is your task:)

Comment: "How does a `sort` function work" may very well have been the exercise.

Comment: Ok, do you have to use recursive algoritm here? Can't you simple extract it to another method? Will help you to test it better.